# WCF netmsmq binding. Retry on client if MSMQ is not available

Tags: wcf, msmq

I know that once a message has been delivered to the MSMQ by a WCF client, the netmsmqbinding provides retries out of the box in case the service faults.

But if my client fails to put the message in the MSMQ in the first place, is there an out of the box client retry available in WCF or do I have to implement a client queue and retry logic in my client code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a highly unlikely scenario that your messages sent to the service will not even be placed in the client queue in the first place, if you have MSMQ server running on the client station and the MSMQ listener service is up and running you should have nothing to worry about. I don't think MSMQ offers anything to check this for you, you should code some method on your client to periodically `Peek()` the local queue and send an acknowledgment receipt for every message that has reached the queue, this is feasible since you can easily access your local queues [in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx) and also every message sent via MSMQ from a client to a service will always go trhough the local queue. You can also tell that the message reaches the queue if your Send() method desn't return an error. But I don't think you really need to worry about message son the client not reaching the local queue first.